# can't find jquery in debugger

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am starting to use Rails 3.2 w/ ruby 1.9.2

When I start the app and look in the debugger and enter, e.g., jQuery('body'), I get "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Seems like I am missing something fundemental.

The Gemfile includes...

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

assets/javascripts/application.js...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include javascripts.js in your layout?

Comment: yep: = javascript_include_tag "application"

Comment: But you  named the file javascripts.js ;) Normally, you would move javascripts.js to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: apologies, the file is assets/javascripts/application.js

Answer (score 0):

Controllers do not have default layout of app/views/layouts/application....

Adding:
    layout 'application'

to the controller fixes problem